# Ubuntu 14.04 is working Slow in Acer Aspire V5-123

Tags: 14.04

I have Upgraded my Ubuntu 12.4 to 14.04 but Ubuntu 14.04 is working Slow in my Acer Aspire V5-123, Its frequently hanging.
Also For Boot It takes more than 5-10 Minutes. 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

### Background.

You shouldn't really upgrade from **12.04** LTS to **14.04** LTS on a laptop/notebook, unless you have specific software installed with settings you need to preserve. *That is usually only relevant for server, and sometimes desktop..*

Any issues introduced in power management, or otherwise laptop specific, may be almost impossible to diagnose and/or address.

---

### Suggested solution.

Backup all data, capture list of installed applications, and note down all favourites or settings.

Then, do a *fresh / clean* install with Ubuntu **14.04.2 LTS (64-bit)**, and look for specific advise on this forum (or elsewhere) for any remaining issues.